# simple thing to know regarding android application publish

Tags: android

I was reading about how to publish android apps on google market. But isn't it possible that i published my app there and someone downloaded it & then provided the apps to someone else.

If so, is there any ways to restrict it?
Sorry , if the question is too much funny for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you do not wish to share your app with rest of population, but want your close friends to download, you can publish under "beta" tab. You then create a group and add your friends to this group.

Comment: dude!! i meant as a developer u would want that pplz will pay for ur app..ri8? not about sharing with specific peoples!!

Comment: If you are worried about people pirating your application, there isn't much you can do. You can obfuscate your code, add serial/activation code, etc, but there will always be people that will go great length to steal the app. I wouldn't worry about it, because if the app is good, people will pay for it.